# Two dimensional array initialization

Tags: c, arrays

i have created an two dimensional array like this:

```
char string_y2m[2][8];
```

Then I just used `memset()` for initialize it by 0:

```
memset(&string_y2m, 0, sizeof(string_y2m));
```

Now I have to assign it some value but it's not working. I have assigned it like this:

```
string_y2m[2][8] = {"2011-1","2011-01"};
```

It's not working, same thing if I do at declaration itself, it works.

Comment: The 'c++' tag has been removed. Was this intentional?

Comment: Apart from what has been mentioned below, memset takes a pointer. Name of a 1D array is already pointer to first element. For a 2D array name is pointer to the first block. Hence using &string_y2m is incorrect for memset.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign strings like that in C, when the target is a character array and you're not also declaring it.

In C, you need to use `strcpy()` to copy the string into the array, paying a lot of attention to the buffer sizes:

```
strcpy(string_y2m[0], "2011-1");
strcpy(string_y2m[1], "2011-01");
```

Or use `snprintf()` if you have it:

```
snprintf(string_y2m[0], sizeof string_y2m[0], "%s", "2011-1");
snprintf(string_y2m[1], sizeof string_y2m[1], "%s", "2011-01");
```

Also, there's no need to clear the space before writing the string there, since writing the string will set the characters to the required values.

Comment: Actually i have to assign some 100 strings so is there any better way then this

Comment: @vivek If you have also string as constants, why don't you write a loop to do the copy?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use assignment but initialize the array correctly from the start:

```
char string_y2m[2][8] = {"2011-1","2011-01"};
```

This will initialize all characters that are not initialized explicitly to `0`.